# Can't Upload JPEGs to live site (PEL error)

Tags: error-message, php, image

I'm unable to upload any jpg/jpeg files to the server, it just comes up with an alert saying "upload failed". After checking the PHP error logs for Craft I found this error message is being created every time I try.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'lsolesen\pel\PelConvert' not found in .../craft/app/vendor/lsolesen/pel/src/PelDataWindow.php on line 96
```

Any advice on how to fix this error?

I've tried:

- Uploading different files to make sure it wasn't an issue with the one jpg
- Uploading different file types (no errors occurred with other image file types)
- Several local server fixes I found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lindseydiloreto in the Craft Slack gave me the solution.

For some reason, the craft/app folder got messed up in the last update.

Re-downloading and replacing the /app folder fixed the problem